# DDestacar fecha en una serie de tiempo en python

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando con series de tiempo en python y me gustaría para el análisis de datos destacar fechas específicas en la serie (por ejemplo, comienzo del aislamiento obligatorio, salida del aislamiento). Es eso posible ? Existe algún código que permita eso. Gracias

Comment: Como no nos des más contexto... ¿Cómo produces la salida del programa? ¿Es en una terminal de texto? ¿En un jupyter notebook? ¿Generas un informe PDF? ¿Una página en HTML?

Comment: Si, estoy trabajando con jupyter notebook y las librerías de pandas y matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

No se muy bien a lo que te refieres con destacar fechas, pero entiendo que si necesitas obtener una fecha, hora o tiempo actual, uses el `timestamp` el cual puedes obtener con las siguientes lineas

```py
import time
print(time.time())
```